# WebMcvTest - no qualifying bean found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-mvc-test

I've an issue while running unit tests for REST controllers using `WebMvcTest` annotation.

It's important to mention that I don't want to bootstrap the whole context using the annotation `@SpringBootTest`. I want to make it work with `@WebMvcTest`.

Here is the test class:

```
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SomeController.class)
class SomeControllerTest {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "/api/something";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private SomeService someService;


    @Test
    void shouldReturnNoContent() throws Exception {
        doNothing().when(pauseJobUseCase).pause(anyString());
        mockMvc.perform(put(BASE_URL, anyString())).andExpect(status().isNoContent());
    }
}
```

and here is the Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${security.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${security.password}")
    private String password;


    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain adminSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
           .securityMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/api/app/**"))
           .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
           .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
           .sessionManagement(
                session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
           )
           .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
           .httpBasic(withDefaults()) // Do not use in production environment!
           .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
           .securityMatcher("/api/auth/**", "/api/admin/**")
           .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
           .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
           .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
           .sessionManagement(
               session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
           )
           .authorizeHttpRequests(
                 authorize -> authorize
                 .requestMatchers("/api-docs/**", "/scheduler-saas.html", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()

                // will be handled on controller level (pre-authorized)
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()

                // "Open" API (requires correct credentials)
                .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
          )
          .build();
     }

     @Bean
     @Order(3)
     public SecurityFilterChain jwtSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JwtFilter jwtFilter)
      throws Exception {
      return http
         .securityMatcher("/api/job/**")
         .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
         .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
         .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
         .sessionManagement(
             session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
         )
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
        .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) 
  {
      var userDetails = User.builder()
          .username(username)
          .password(passwordEncoder.encode(password))
          .roles("ADMIN")
          .build();

      return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
  }

  public record AccessViolationResponse(String message, String localizedMessage) {
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

> No qualifying bean of type
> 'com.hedza06.saasscheduler.security.jwt.JwtTokenProvider' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations: {}

I've read this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31162) but it wasn't helpful.

The tech stack I'm using is the following:

- Java 21
- Spring Boot 3.1.4
- Spring Security Core [6.1.4]

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems that you don't import your `com.hedza06.saasscheduler.security.jwt.JwtTokenProvider`, which is apparently your custom bean

Comment: To import it where?

Comment: It looks like this import solves the issue: @Import(value = {SecurityConfig.class, JwtTokenProvider.class})

Comment: It does not make much sense,  importing a component shouldn't do anything, what is this JwtTokenProvider class ?

Comment: @Chasca JwtTokenProvider is a class responsible for generating and validating JWT tokens. It's injected in JwtFilter which verifies the token and populates Security Context Holder with required data.

Comment: Right but it is not a Configuration so importing it shouldn't allow Spring to define it as a bean and make things magically work. Unless I am mistaken and you can actually import Component/Service/Controller. But the real workaround for your problem should to define a `@Configuration` class test where you provide the @Bean which is a JwtTokenProvider

Comment: It's totally okay to import component, also we can create `@TestConfiguration` (not `@Configuration`) with the JwtTokenProvider bean